# Read run-time know, heap allocated objects from binary file

Tags: c++

A lil description of a program that I'm writing...
The user can create as many `profiles` as they want, these profiles are heap allocated, and there's a global vector of pointers to those profiles, now I want to add a data saving system for those profiles, so I've used binary files to store them, but I have no idea how am I going to read them if they're run-time know, heap allocated. Any ideas?

This is my writing function (I'm making it with Qt 6, but that ain't relevant).

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("profiles_saves.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        for (auto p : profiles) // <<< std::vector of pointers to heap allocated Profiles
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p), sizeof(*p));

        outFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not write to 'profiles_saves.txt'.";
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea of how to write the reading function?

Comment: What is `profiles`?

Comment: @goodvibration just a custom class, but it has `std::strings` so they have a varing size

Comment: In either case, I think that what you really want is to save the contents of those heap-allocated objects, not their addresses, which may be invalid by the time you process the file which stores them.

Comment: @goodvibration `outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p), sizeof(*p))` is correct isn't it?? since `p` is a pointer, I cast it to `char*` and with the size of what it points to, so `*p`

Comment: With `p` of type `char*`, the expression `sizeof(*p)` evaluates to `1` by the language standard (i.e., on every compiler and for every platform). You wanna use `void*` and `sizeof(Profile)`, assuming that you have such structure. Note that if `Profile` contains pointers to other structures or strings or blocks of data in general, then you won't be storing the actual contents of those data blocks, but only their addresses.

Comment: @goodvibration well `Profile` has everything you said, sooooo ... I still in the same situation

Comment: @goodvibration so you can't store objects with all that suff you mentioned in binary files??

Comment: @Karlos: Of course you can, but you need to implement your function specifically for the `Profile` structure. More generally, this process (i.e., that function) is known as *object serialization*.